# Comparing line in external file with a variable and and replacing it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a scoreboard in an external file in python and having a bit of an issue.

```
score = 14



with open("score.txt") as f:
   data_1 = f.read()
   lines = data_1.split("\n")
   line_1 = lines[0]
   line_1 = int(line_1)

if line_1 < score:
    score = str(score)
    with open("score.txt", "w") as a:
        a.write(score)
```

Every time I'd run the code, it would write 14 in the first line and then delete everything else in the file.

I want the code to check if `score` is bigger than the first line in the file and if it is, shift everything down a line and put `score` there instead and if it is smaller than the first line do the same with the others

Comment: By default, values in the file are treated as `str`. You could try changing that to `int` before comparing.

Comment: You are opening the file with `"w"` option. If you want to write anything to that file, it will overwrite it.

Comment: Open the file in append mode, `with open(f_name,"a") as f: #do_anything_with_f`

Comment: agree with @bigbounty on another note, using SQLite could be a rather "cleaner" approach for a scoreboard